# Export public key to decompressed (x,y) representation begins with 0x04 and has 65 bytes length

Tags: ios, objective-c, elliptic-curve

I have below sample code for generating private key (link to gist):
https://gist.github.com/kynwu/3a65e238fcd189d516bb2de59527a320

after generated private key, I derived public key by calling `SecKeyCopyPublicKey((SecKeyRef)privateKey)`

I got below value showing (x,y) of the public key.

```
<SecKeyRef curve type: kSecECCurveSecp256r1, algorithm id: 3, key type: ECPublicKey, version: 4, block size: 256 bits, y: 1778DB79819A67BC9211E003557CB55EA0C7A19154B1C0828B30F30AD208ABCD, x: 7A1C65A955F46B9937A12E19139DE25C3F19368A3C2DD7360791E42382C98716, addr: 0x1003019f0>
```

Now, I want to transfer this (x,y) to `0x04|x-32bytes|y-32bytes`which is 65 bytes binary data, thus I can output this binary represents the public key to server. How to achieve this?

Comment: Does SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation() on the public key not work?  If it does, that returns the value in the uncompressed format.

Comment: Whats the difference between SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation() and SecKeyCopyPublicKey((SecKeyRef)privateKey)?

Answer (score 0):

Use CoreFoundation's CFDictionaryGetValue method.

const void *CFDictionaryGetValue(CFDictionaryRef theDict, const void *key);

Below function will give 65 bytes UnCompressed public key.

```
+ (NSData *) publicKeyBits
```

{

```
return (NSData *) CFDictionaryGetValue((CFDictionaryRef)[self lookupPublicKeyRef], kSecValueData);
```

}

```
  + (SecKeyRef) lookupPublicKeyRef
{
  CFMutableDictionaryRef getPublicKeyQuery = newCFDict;
  CFDictionarySetValue(getPublicKeyQuery, kSecClass,                kSecClassKey);
  CFDictionarySetValue(getPublicKeyQuery, kSecAttrKeyType,          kSecAttrKeyTypeEC);
  CFDictionarySetValue(getPublicKeyQuery, kSecAttrApplicationTag,   kPublicKeyName);
  CFDictionarySetValue(getPublicKeyQuery, kSecAttrKeyClass,         kSecAttrKeyClassPublic);
  CFDictionarySetValue(getPublicKeyQuery, kSecReturnData,           kCFBooleanTrue);
  CFDictionarySetValue(getPublicKeyQuery, kSecReturnPersistentRef,  kCFBooleanTrue);

  OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching(getPublicKeyQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKeyRef);
  if (status == errSecSuccess)
    return (SecKeyRef)publicKeyRef;
  else if (status == errSecItemNotFound)
    return nil;
  else
    [NSException raise:@"Unexpected OSStatus" format:@"Status: %i", status];
  return false;
}
```

- kPublicKeyName can be any constant string to be associated as a tag to public key.

for example - `#define kPublicKeyName @"com.trailer.ECKey.public"`